# Why is 'self' available in a prototype's member function?

Tags: javascript, prototype, self

I have often seen, and used, `self` as a data member to guarantee proper access to the root object inside all nested scopes:

```
function Foo() {
    var self = this; // Common design pattern
}
```

However, I do not understand why `self` is defined in the following code snippet (see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel347x/62b2feLe/)):

```
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.foo = function() {
    // Returns 'object'!  Why is 'self' defined?
    console.log("typeof self = " + typeof self);
}

var f = new Foo();
f.foo(); // Prints "typeof self = object"
```

Can someone please explain why `self` is available inside a function defined on the `prototype` object for a function.

Comment: [That `self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) in the prototype method is not your instance.

Comment: Didn't realize `self` was defined in the global object.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a property on the global `window` object, so it doesn't need to be prefixed with `window` to use it. Since `window` is an object, that's what the console spits out, but that `console.log` line could be anywhere that `self` is not redefined to mean something else and would give the same output.

When you see developers declare a variable called `self`, they are creating a more local definition for the identifier and **it hides the global self** for the duration of that scope.

Example:

```
// In the global scope:
console.log(self);  // window

function foo(){
  // this declaration will hide the global self with a local version
  // only good for this function
  var self = this;  // or whatever

  console.log(self);  // Depends on how foo is invoked
}
```

If you modify your example code, slightly to:

```
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype.foo = function() {
    // Returns 'object'!  Why is 'self' defined?
    console.log(self); // <-- not typeof self
}

var f = new Foo();
f.foo(); // Prints window
```

By the way, this is why often, developers will not use the word `self`, instead they will use `that`:

```
 var that = this;
```